# Print text including line returns in PHP

Tags: php

I am pulling text from a database and I want to print out the text and include the line returns so the text is readable and not all compressed into one paragraph.

Is this possible and if so what is the PHP function.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you include any examples of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that you get `\n` out of the database. Because HTML ignores whitespace, then those `\n` will be ignored by your browser.

You can use the [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.nl2br.php) function to convert all `\n` to `<br />` tags.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks Etienne de Martel.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the HTML < pre > tag or nl2br($string)

Answer (score 1):

You could either change the header to text/plain:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo $db_text;
```

Or you could replace new lines with breaks:

```
echo nl2br($db_text);
```